# breezejs - schemaless complex properties

Tags: json, postgresql, breeze

Is there a way to do schemaless complex properties in Breeze JS?

I've got a use-case where I need to store customer-specific lookup tables. These lookup tables can have any number of columns and rows. My preferred solution is to store these as a JSON object of the form:

{'columns':['one', 'two', 'three'], 'rows':[{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three', 3}]}

In the backend this isn't a problem, I can store it as a JSON object in postgres. I just can't figure out how to get breeze to treat this object as-is, and not do any processing on it.

Is there a way to do schemaless complex properties in Breeze JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a property with a DataType of 'Undefined', Breeze will serialize the data  without trying to convert or coerce it.

```
     var et = new EntityType({
        shortName: "Foo",
        namespace: "Sample.Models"
    });
    et.addProperty( new DataProperty({
        name: "columns",
        dataType: DataType.Undefined
    }));
```

Note that as of Breeze 1.4.0, we also now support nonscalar dataproperties so you could also do the following.

```
  et.addProperty( new DataProperty({
        name: "columns",
        dataType: DataType.String
        isScalar: false
    }));
```

Also, not shown, you can actually create properties that are arrays of complexTypes.  See the Breeze Node/Mongo samples for an example of this kind of metadata. (This could be used for your 'rows' property).